Issues with cutsom NodeJS OpenID connect provider and Portainer
My Custom NodeJS OpenID Connect Provider
app.js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

// Server setup
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
}));

// In-memory user store
const users = [
    {
        username: 'john.doe',
        email: 'john.doe@example.com',
        passwordHash: bcrypt.hashSync('password', 10),
        profile: {
            name: 'John Doe',
            email: 'john.doe@example.com',
        }
    }
];

// Load client configuration and JWKS
const clients = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './clients.json')));
const jwks = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './jwks.json')));

// Authorization code store
let authCodeStore = {};

// JWKS route
app.get('/.well-known/jwks.json', (req, res) => {
    res.json(jwks);
});

// OpenID Configuration route
app.get('/.well-known/openid-configuration', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        issuer: process.env.ISSUER,
        authorization_endpoint: `${process.env.ISSUER}/auth/authorize`,
        token_endpoint: `${process.env.ISSUER}/token`,
        jwks_uri: `${process.env.ISSUER}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
        response_types_supported: ['code'],
        subject_types_supported: ['public'],
        id_token_signing_alg_values_supported: ['RS256'],
        scopes_supported: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
        token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported: ['client_secret_basic'],
        grant_types_supported: ['authorization_code'],
    });
});

// Authorization endpoint (Step 1 of OIDC flow)
app.get('/auth/authorize', (req, res) => {
    const { client_id, redirect_uri, scope, response_type, state, code_challenge } = req.query;

    console.log('Received authorization request', { client_id, redirect_uri, scope, response_type, state, code_challenge });

    const client = clients.find(c => c.client_id === client_id && c.redirect_uri === redirect_uri);
    if (!client || !scope.split(' ').every(s => client.allowed_scopes.includes(s))) {
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid client or scope');
    }

    // Check for PKCE requirement
    if (client.usePkce && !code_challenge) {
        return res.status(400).send('PKCE code challenge required');
    }

    // Check for an existing session in a cookie or Authorization header
    let token = req.cookies?.session_token;
    console.log('Token from cookie', token);

    if (!token && req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    }

    // If the user has a valid JWT session, skip login and issue an authorization code
    if (token) {
        try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
            const username = decoded.sub;

            // Generate authorization code
            const authCode = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
            authCodeStore[authCode] = { username, client_id, code_challenge: client.usePkce ? code_challenge : null };

            // Redirect with authorization code
            const redirectURL = `${redirect_uri}?code=${authCode}&state=${state}`;
            return res.redirect(redirectURL);
        } catch (err) {
            // If JWT is invalid, clear the cookie or continue with the login form
            res.clearCookie('session_token');
        }
    }

    // If no valid session, show the login form
    res.send(`
      <html>
        <body>
          <form action="/auth/login" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="${client_id}">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="${redirect_uri}">
            <input type="hidden" name="state" value="${state}">
            <input type="hidden" name="code_challenge" value="${code_challenge}">
            <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /></label><br />
            <label>Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></label><br />
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>
    `);
});

// Login route (Step 2 of OIDC flow)
app.post('/auth/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password, client_id, redirect_uri, code_challenge, state } = req.body;
    const user = users.find(u => u.username === username);

    if (!user || !bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.passwordHash)) {
        return res.status(401).send('Invalid credentials');
    }

    // Generate JWT session token
    const sessionToken = jwt.sign(
        {
            sub: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            name: user.profile.name
        },
        process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        { expiresIn: '1h' }
    );

    // Set session token as a cookie
    res.cookie('session_token', sessionToken, { httpOnly: true });

    // Generate authorization code
    const authCode = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    authCodeStore[authCode] = { username, client_id, code_challenge };

    // Redirect with authorization code
    const redirectURL = `${redirect_uri}?code=${authCode}&state=${state}`;
    res.redirect(redirectURL);
});

// Token exchange endpoint (Step 3 of OIDC flow)
app.post('/token', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Token request with body', req.body);
    const { code, redirect_uri, code_verifier } = req.body;

    // Validate the authorization code
    const authData = authCodeStore[code];
    console.log('Stored authorization data', authData);
    if (!authData) {
        console.log('Invalid authorization code');
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid authorization code');
    }

    // Identify the client using the redirect_uri instead of client_id
    const client = clients.find(c => c.redirect_uri === redirect_uri);
    console.log('Found client by redirect_uri', client);
    if (!client) {
        console.log('Invalid redirect_uri');
        return res.status(400).send('Invalid redirect_uri');
    }

    // PKCE verification (only if usePkce is true)
    if (client.usePkce) {
        const expectedChallenge = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(code_verifier).digest('base64url');
        console.log('Expected challenge', expectedChallenge);
        if (authData.code_challenge !== expectedChallenge) {
            console.log('PKCE verification failed');
            return res.status(400).send('PKCE verification failed');
        }
    }

    const user = users.find(u => u.username === authData.username);

    // Load the private key for signing
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('private.pem', 'utf8');

    // Issue JWT token (ID Token)
    const id_token = jwt.sign(
        {
            sub: authData.username,
            email: user.email,
            name: user.profile.name,
            iss: process.env.ISSUER,
            aud: client.client_id  // Use client_id for consistency
        },
        privateKey,
        {
            algorithm: 'RS256',
            expiresIn: '1h',
            keyid: '4c460476f440dfac684b8f3ef0fe6933fb9b35c0a6bc0d825267a4172c5fe616'   // This must match the 'kid' in the JWKS
        }
    );

    // Generate access_token similarly
    const access_token = jwt.sign(
        {
            sub: authData.username,
            scope: 'openid profile email',
            aud: client.client_id  // Use client_id here as well
        },
        privateKey,
        {
            algorithm: 'RS256',
            expiresIn: '1h',
            keyid: '4c460476f440dfac684b8f3ef0fe6933fb9b35c0a6bc0d825267a4172c5fe616'   // This must match the 'kid' in the JWKS
        }
    );

    console.log('Returning tokens', { access_token, id_token });
    res.json({
        access_token: access_token,
        id_token: id_token,
        token_type: 'Bearer'
    });

    // Delete the authorization code from the store to prevent reuse
    delete authCodeStore[code];
});

// UserInfo endpoint (JWT validation included)
app.get('/userinfo', (req, res) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    }

    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

        const user = users.find(u => u.username === decoded.sub);
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(404).send('User not found');
        }

        res.json({
            sub: user.username,
            email: user.email,
            name: user.profile.name
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(401).send('Invalid token');
    }
});

// Home route
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to OIDC Provider');
});

// Start server
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});

clients.json
[
    {
        "client_id": "portainer_local",
        "client_secret": "portainer_local",
        "redirect_uri": "https://192.168.0.187:9443",
        "allowed_scopes": [
            "openid",
            "profile",
            "email"
        ],
        "usePkce": false
    }
]

jwks.json
{
    "keys": [
        {
            "kty": "RSA",
            "n": "pbnssr4_gV0iu08BRzofEcBu82L59Zn24fXaolozLIkFrIGlgVzlQeZOD2dJldjWtPM3Q8vfIOrDdl56fYta4xNZgss6mIm0b3RiEwlmghp8VuodoIIZXobfxlVTgPVLAIFWMTa-h0ELna2-bWxAiKelNTicvxXk4eserFGI6TRnyx6zJ9exoVFb44GFNrn_BFGrjyU5LRIH3GYJHV0TFyPQ7GlfGa3fbDgRF1U6wmTb7QZCGz0o54uEN0lCm5jEEbHzOlU46cRE9Mbcbfovdq82nYJxsNxK9MQ-178nA7qZ8vdXNqmairSrhNyFLW6ooBTAgUnWbkqjva2eYfrX5Q",
            "e": "AQAB",
            "kid": "4c460476f440dfac684b8f3ef0fe6933fb9b35c0a6bc0d825267a4172c5fe616",
            "use": "sig",
            "alg": "RS256"
        }
    ]
}

.env
PORT=3000
ISSUER=http://192.168.0.187:3000
JWT_SECRET=4c460476f440dfac684b8f3ef0fe6933fb9b35c0a6bc0d825267a4172c5fe616

The problem:
I have a portainer instance running on my local machine, and as seen by my clients.json file i have configured my OIDC provider as a provider for my portainer. Here is a screenshot of my portainer config below:


The issue i am having is whenever the oidc flow completes (which it does and works fine and everything, even with every other client like cloudflare which i have tested with it) i get an Unable to login via OAuth error on the login screen. I then enabled debug mode on portainer and got this:
2024-09-10 21:32:10 2024/09/10 11:32AM DBG github.com/portainer/portainer/api/http/security/bouncer.go:309 > HTTP error | error=Unauthorized msg="A valid authorization token is missing" status_code=401
2024-09-10 21:32:12 2024/09/10 11:32AM DBG github.com/portainer/portainer/api/http/security/bouncer.go:309 > HTTP error | error=Unauthorized msg="A valid authorization token is missing" status_code=401
2024-09-10 21:32:12 2024/09/10 11:32AM DBG github.com/portainer/portainer/api/oauth/oauth.go:46 > failed retrieving resource | error="oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized\nResponse: Invalid token"
2024-09-10 21:32:12 2024/09/10 11:32AM DBG github.com/portainer/portainer/api/http/handler/auth/authenticate_oauth.go:76 > OAuth authentication error | error="oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized\nResponse: Invalid token"
2024-09-10 21:32:12 2024/09/10 11:32AM DBG github.com/portainer/portainer/api/http/security/bouncer.go:514 > HTTP error | error=Unauthorized msg="Unable to authenticate through OAuth" status_code=500

So how do i fix it and where is the issue, because portainer is the only client having problems with it as far as my testing.
Thanks Heaps!
